# SIP call with C# using Ozeki throws state exception

Tags: c#, sip

I want to make call with sip using Ozeki library.
But this library throws me state excepton.
I use asteriks telephony in the server.
My code is below:

```
class Program
    {
        static ISoftPhone softphone;   // softphone object
        static IPhoneLine phoneLine;   // phoneline object
        static IPhoneCall call;
        static Microphone microphone;
        static Speaker speaker;
        static MediaConnector connector;
        static PhoneCallAudioSender mediaSender;
        static PhoneCallAudioReceiver mediaReceiver;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a softphone object with RTP port range 5000-10000
            softphone = SoftPhoneFactory.CreateSoftPhone(1, 10000);

            // SIP account registration data, (supplied by your VoIP service provider)
            var registrationRequired = true;
            var userName = "111";
            var displayName = "111";
            var authenticationId = "111";
            var registerPassword = "pin111";
            var domainHost = "localhost";
            var domainPort = 5038;

            var account = new SIPAccount(registrationRequired, displayName, userName, authenticationId, registerPassword, domainHost, domainPort);

            // Send SIP regitration request
            RegisterAccount(account);

            microphone = Microphone.GetDefaultDevice();
            speaker = Speaker.GetDefaultDevice();
            mediaSender = new PhoneCallAudioSender();
            mediaReceiver = new PhoneCallAudioReceiver();
            connector = new MediaConnector();

            // Prevents the termination of the application
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void RegisterAccount(SIPAccount account)
        {
            try
            {
                phoneLine = softphone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
                phoneLine.RegistrationStateChanged += line_RegStateChanged;
                softphone.RegisterPhoneLine(phoneLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error during SIP registration: " + ex);
            }
        }

        static void line_RegStateChanged(object sender, RegistrationStateChangedArgs e)
        {
            if (e.State == RegState.NotRegistered || e.State == RegState.Error)
                Console.WriteLine("Registration failed!");

            if (e.State == RegState.RegistrationSucceeded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registration succeeded - Online!");
                CreateCall();
            }
        }

        private static void CreateCall()
        {
            var numberToDial = "00994122000020";
            call = softphone.CreateCallObject(phoneLine, numberToDial);
            call.CallStateChanged += call_CallStateChanged;
            call.Start();
        }

        private static void SetupDevices()
        {
            connector.Connect(microphone, mediaSender);
            connector.Connect(mediaReceiver, speaker);

            mediaSender.AttachToCall(call);
            mediaReceiver.AttachToCall(call);

            microphone.Start();
            speaker.Start();
        }

        static void call_CallStateChanged(object sender, CallStateChangedArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call state: {0}.", e.State);

            if (e.State == CallState.Answered)
                SetupDevices();
        }
    }
```

This code show me this error message:
Registration succeeded - Online!
Call state: Setup.
Call state: Error.

What is the problem? What must I chane for working this code?
P.S Please, If you know the better library for making call with asteriks you can tell me.

Comment: How it related to asterisk after all? Have you tried to use tracer/debuger?

Comment: SIP is typically not on port 5038.

Comment: It used UDP in network

Comment: It's okay. Everything is working, but I have a new problem. I couldn't call a home phone in the country code and plus home phone number. I mean I call a local phones in the office, but I couldn't call to home phone numbers/